# Grep count matches above 'X'

Tags: grep

I am trying to figure out a command that matches all counts above certain counts. I am using

```
grep -src 'Bicycle' /cygdrive/c/Documents/* |grep -v ':0$'
```

and the output is:

```
/cygdrive/c/Documents/blahhh.txt:1
/cygdrive/c/Documents/blahhh.txt:3
/cygdrive/c/Documents/bla0.txt:5
/cygdrive/c/Documents/blahg.txt:23
```

But i only want it to output:

```
/cygdrive/c/Documents/blahg.txt:23
```

I have searched quite a bit for this one. If someone can lead me in the right direction it would awesome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple way to do this would be to pipe the output of `grep` to `awk` and parse it by setting a de-limiter as `:` and check if the last field count is greater than the `X` what you are trying to define

```
grep -src 'Bicycle' /cygdrive/c/Documents/* | awk -F: '$NF+0 > 1'
```

In the example above, I've taken out the count of occurrences greater than `1`. Modify it as you need.

The reason to have `$NF+0 > 1` over just `$NF > 1` is to do a pure numeric evaluation, consider a case when an empty string or a numeric string is present, adding `0` puts it to a proper numerical for comparing, else we have incorrect types on both sides of the comparison.

From [How `awk` Converts Between Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html)

> If, for some reason, you need to force a number to be converted to a string, concatenate that number with the empty string, `""`. To force a string to be converted to a number, add zero to that string.

Comment: This is what i was looking for! Thank you

Comment: Why `$NF+0>1` and not just `$NF>1`...?

Comment: +1. this is one of the very few instances where it's useful and sensible to pipe `grep` into `awk`.   you could write an awk script to count the matches found (and use find or a shell that understands `**` for recursion - e.g. bash with globstar set, or zsh) but it's much simpler and easier just to do this.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v min=10 '
  BEGINFILE{n=0}
  /Bicycle/ {n++}
  ENDFILE{if (n >= min) print FILENAME":"n}' /cygdrive/c/Documents/*
```

Note that it counts the number of *lines* that contain `Bicycle`, not the number of occurrences of the `Bicycle` *word*. For that, you'd need:

```
awk -v min=10 '
  BEGINFILE{n=0}
  {n += gsub(/Bicycle/, "&")}
  ENDFILE{if (n >= min) print FILENAME":"n}' /cygdrive/c/Documents/*
```

For recursive search:

```
find /cygdrive/c/Documents -type f -exec awk -v min=10 '
  BEGINFILE{n=0}
  /Bicycle/ {n++}
  ENDFILE{if (n >= min) print FILENAME":"n}' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Method1

```
 grep -c   "Bicycle" * |sed -r "s/\s+//g" | awk -F ":"  '{print $1,$2}' | sort -nr -k2| head -1
```

Method2

Here i consisdered to display the files with counts which having count greater than 3

```
grep -c   "Bicycle" * |sed -r "s/\s+//g" | awk -F ":"  '$2 > "3"{print $1,$2}'
```